# In which order are the index files used to serve a search query in Lucene?

Tags: lucene, indexing

When a search query is made against Lucene, what files (as described in http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/fileformats.html) are accesses and in what order? For example, once the query has been tokenized into a list of terms, what file is used to convert those terms into hit lists (of document IDs)? Once we have the document IDs, how do we look up the relevant documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical search requires informations from the following files:

1. term dictionary to get information about the terms in your query
2. frequencies to get the doc IDs that match the query

   - the deleted docs file is used to skip over deleted documents
   - the norms file is used to score documents
   - if the query requires positions (phrase query for example) to be processed then the positions file will be read too
3. stored fields to get summary results of your top hits
4. term vectors to highlight the stored fields content

Comment: Are the files used in the following order: .tip -> .tim -> .doc? In other words, do we first find the term in the .tim file, using the index in the .tip file and then, once we've found the term in the .tim file, do we look up (among other things) the posting list in the .doc file? Doesn't Lucene keep any in-memory structures to avoid linear searching of blocks?

Comment: This is the right order for the files. Regarding access, the terms index is partially in memory (to make things fast while still being able to handle indexes that have *many* distinct terms with a reasonable amount of memory) and postings lists have skip lists.